# The following layers were not correctly generated. Grid

Tags: qgis, dem, error

I keep getting the same error:

> The following layers were not correctly
>   generated.
>
> - Grid
>
> You can check the log messages to find
>   more information about the execution of the algorithm

I saw two post about it on this forum but none of them helped me. I see that that it is related to the Grid but I don't know what it means (I used EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 and I put 0,0005 instead of 100 to convert in degrees).

[image]

**EDIT:**
My version of QGIS is 2.18.1 Las Palmas (the last one). I followed this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLbY3iMBW-A) from 5:00 to 9:00 and I used 0,0005.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of QGIS?

Comment: Can you copy and paste the whole log. Also did you use 0,0005 or 0.0005?

Comment: I edited my post to answer your questions.

Comment: In the last option "Grid", can you try the "[Save to temporary file]" option, so don't type anything into the box or use the "..." button. Also before editing the 100.0000 to 0,0005 does the 100 have a . or a ,?

Comment: It has a , but  I chose "[Save to temporary file]" like you said and it worked thank you !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the error message and what ended up working, there is likely something wrong with the path that you used to save the file in.

Like what worked, you can choose to use the "[Save to temporary file]" option.

Or you may want to work with a folder that has no spaces in it. For example: "C:\GIS".

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when there was not enough space on my hard drive to save the file.