# Error: Grid layer was not correctly generated

Tags: qgis, error, algorithm, resolution, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

Faced this error already several times when I was playing with processing algorithms:

[image]

I used hi-res DSM/DEMs out of UAV surveys.

Resolution between 2,5 - 5 cm GSD. Output format: .tif

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Please be more specific about your problem. Which processing alg are you trying to run? What CRS are you using?

Comment: Hi! This was attempt to perform Multilevel b-spline interpolation from raster.

Comment: What versions of QGIS and SAGA are you using?

Comment: QGIS: 2.18.5; SAGA: 2.3.2

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question and input from [The following layers were not correctly generated. Grid](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221924/the-following-layers-were-not-correctly-generated-grid)

> there is likely something wrong with the path that you used to save the file in.
>
> Like what worked, you can choose to use the "[Save to temporary file]" option.
>
> Or you may want to work with a folder that has no spaces in it. For example: "C:\GIS".

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. In fact, it did not work even when I modified the path to avoid spaces. Still trying to figure out what may be a reason, but this is not the first time that technology do not want to cooperate without clear reason :)