# QGIS (3.10.7) SAGA tools resulting in "The following layers were not correctly generated."

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, saga

I am using QGIS 3.10.7 and want to use SAGA tools. I am using an ASCII file (.asc) with a projected coordinate system - EPSG:26919 - NAD83 / UTM zone 19N - Projected.

When attempting to use the tools, they always result in a message like this -

> "The following layers were not correctly
> generated.
>
> C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_7cf0f5b0db874bb9a6b8fe84b44cb047/2a6b2113845f4739b4dec0f12c451504/C_PROF.sdat"

I read a similar post, that recommended "[save to temporary file]." I tried that and it still does not work. [The following layers were not correctly generated. Grid](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221924/the-following-layers-were-not-correctly-generated-grid). I also don't believe that I have any spaces in my file extension as seen in the error message.

Despite the error, it ends up outputting values. The values seem reasonable, but I am of course suspicious of them given that it says they were not correctly generated.

I first had this issue on my Mac. I tried multiple versions of QGIS and still had the issue. Now I am using a PC with 3.10.7 - still getting the same message.

Any ideas?

Comment: What size (MB or GB) is the file your are working with roughly? I had similar issues and there it appeared to be a memory/disk space problem. When your input is very big sometimes your operating system won't let QGIS take the large amount of disk space it would need. Could you try a smaller portion of your data and see if it works?

Comment: I attempted with a 1.7GB ascii file and a 280MB ascii file. Both had the same error. I have an old version of QGIS on my PC (2.12.3 Lyon) and this will run SAGA tools without reporting an error. But, when I load the same ascii file into QGIS 2.12.3 it reads the range of values in my ascii file as 267.966 - 1142.93 whereas QGIS 3.10.7 shows the same ascii file as having a range of values from 186.573 - 1458.33. That seems a bit strange, no?

Comment: That loks like QGIS 2.12.3 is tailcutting somewhere on the line. Are these the readings from the properties of the file or from the display band?

Comment: I believe both. I assume the display band is the left side bar with the heading "layers"?  The display bands for QGIS 3.10.7 reads, 186.573 - 1458.33. In the settings for QGIS 3.10.7, the information is the same as the display band, STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE=YES
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=1458.328
STATISTICS_MEAN=588.72782128073
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=186.5734
STATISTICS_STDDEV=215.02881738138
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=59.69
In QGIS 2.12.3, the display band reads 267.966 - 1142.93. In the properties, it shows the min and max with the same values, but you seem to be able to manipulate the values

Comment: I just posted another question about the discrepancy in values between the versions of QGIS. ArcMap interprets the same ASCII file differently also. Are ASCII files interpreted differently by different programs? 
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366111/arcmap-qgis-3-10-7-qgis-2-12-3-all-interpret-ascii-file-values-differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error has been occurring with QGIS since version 3.6.0. Be sure to confirm that the error message reads similar to the one shown above, though. Despite the error, the values produced seem to be accurate. Read the provided post and accepted answer for full details on this error.

[Do SAGA tools work on QGIS 3.10.7?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366138/do-saga-tools-work-on-qgis-3-10-7/366770#366770)