# ArcMap, QGIS 3.10.7, QGIS 2.12.3 all interpret ASCII file values differently

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, ascii, esri-ascii-raster

I have QGIS 3.10.7 and QGIS 2.12.3. I am loading the same ASCII (.asc) file into both versions of QGIS. QGIS 3.10.7 says the values in the ASCII file range from 186.573 - 1458.33. QGIS 2.12.3 says the values range from 267.966 - 1142.93.

ArcMap says the range is 549.979 - 1462.79.

Do different programs interpret ASCII files differently? If I were to use SAGA tools to calculate something like slope/aspect/topographic position index using the different programs, I assume the results would be different in absolute terms, but would they be the same/similar in relative terms?

Comment: Have you made sure you use the same CRS in all GIS?

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed that the CRS are all the same. I am using EPSG:26919 - NAD83 / UTM zone 19N - Projected. Still, the values are different in all three programs.

Comment: How are you checkinc the values?

Comment: Are you sure that the range you get are from the whole value and not from a subset, check the option on all 3 software

Comment: Link to test data would leave less space for quessing. Also describe how did you exactly get the values so it would be possible to do the same.

Comment: Does ArcMap show the min/max of data? Or does if report the highest and lowest value used for stretching the color ramp?

Comment: ArcMap 10.7: Looking at 'Table of contents,' it lists the high (1462.79) and low (549.979) value
QGIS 3.10.7: Looking at 'Layers' lists high (1458.33) and low (186.573). Also properties of layer > Band 1 > STATISTICS_MINIMUM = 186.5734, STATISTICS_MAXIMUM = 1458.328
QGIS 2.12.3: Looking at 'Layers' lists high (1142.93) and low (267.966). Also layer properties > Histogram > Min = 267.966, Max = 1142.93

Comment: Accessing data: https://unh.box.com/s/uuk0qcb7e13n5ap412v538mj9ewxbem8
Let me know if there is a better way to provide the data than this.

Comment: @J.R, I am not sure how to check other than the way that I described in my recent comment. Is the way that I am checking values not correct?

Comment: I converted the  file to a TIFF (.tif) to see if the ASCII (.asc) file format is the cause. The same thing happens with TIFF. All three programs read the max and min differently. ArcMap: low (184.57) high (1462.79). QGIS 3.10.7: low (243.826) high (1270.77). QGIS 2.12.3: low (294.146) high (1159.86).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QGIS is just estimating the statistics from a sample, instead of calculating the actual statistics from all of the values.

In the QGIS layer properties - Symbology - Min / Max Value Settings change the Accuracy setting from Estimate (faster) to Actual (slower).

[image]

Comment: while the accuracy is set to "estimate'', will it produce different results than the accuracy set to -'Actual', for any raster processing such as zonal statistics?

Comment: The statistics this q refers to are only used for display. They don't affect processing.