# Elevation discrepancy while clipping a DEM in QGIS 3.28.9

Tags: gdal, dem, qgis-processing

I clipped a DEM (Clipped mask) using the GDAL Processing Tool - clip raster by mask layer from a DEM (clipped).
The maximum elevation value of the Clipped mask is 7286m, while the same in the clipped layer is 7082. How is this even possible, as the Clipped mask layer is a subset of the clipped layer?[image]

Comment: I suppose you have faced the difference between computed statistics and estimated statistics. Estimated statistics are fast to get but not exact. See for example https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366111/arcmap-qgis-3-10-7-qgis-2-12-3-all-interpret-ascii-file-values-differently/366145#366145.